# Generate an image from a chart visualforce page renderedAs pdf

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex, visualforce, apexcharts

Hello I have a problem with a visualforce page renderedAs pdf, I need to display chart with apexchart but it's impossible to run javascript in a visualforce renderedAs pdf. My question is, is there any solution for doing that? I was thinking to calling another visualforce page (from the one renderedAs pdf) not rendered As pdf and run javascript there, then generate the data:image/png;base64 and returning this url from the second visualforce page (the one not renderedAs pdf) to apex controller. I don't know if this can be done.
I hope someone can help me. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you need browser to run the JavaScript chart libraries. You'll have hard time with it.

You could generate the image earlier (user clicking something on VF page, your JS running, grabbing contents of  element or however the chart is done, calling [toDataUrl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL), saving as file/attachment somewhere) and then the pdf page can just reference the file.

There are charting solutions on the web that return an image similar to https://developers.google.com/chart/image but it's ancient and well... you'd need to learn new API and be OK with sending your data to some 3rd party to get the image back. Probably a lot of them will be paid too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I saw google chart are too old, I was thinking to create an app in java with spring controller and this controller return me an image in base64 but I dont know how to do it, I mean I did it but I doesn't work :(

Comment: Good idea. It would have to be accessible from internet, can't be just on localhost / local network. If you managed to view your image in a normal (non pdf) VF page but pdf doesn't want to play - make sure your server is added to Setup -> Remote Site Settings.

Comment: Yes I did it, the problem is that in java when i call my controller then the jsp, when I run javascript inside the jsp and generate the image from the chart it takes too much and I did not get the image on my visualforce page rendered as pdf :(

Comment: I think you need to forget JavaScript entirely, your JSP will not be seen by a browser. You need some serverside java/python/c#/whatever returning images. Well, I guess Node.js counts too if your library has npm package, might be an option.